# Inertiajs - Asynch Redirect

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a short question.
Does inertia render asynch?

I realized, as soon I delete a DB - Entry, while I connect to new Nav-Link direct afterwards (Inertia.onStart)- which redirects me on another Page, the changes (onSuccess) wont be showed up.

```
            Inertia.post('data-delete', {
                id: this.meeeh.data[index].id,
            }, {
                preserveScroll: true,
                onBefore: () => {
                    window.Toast.confirm('Delete?');
                },
                onStart: (visit) => {
                    window.Toast.load('Delete...');
                },
                onSuccess: (page) => {
                    return Promise.all([
                        window.Toast.success(page.props.toast),     
                        /** Wont show after click another Link in Navbar */
                    ])
                },
                onError: (errors) => {
                    window.Toast.error(errors);
                }
            });
```

How does it come, I have to wait until the process is Finished - otherwise my Page is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you're looking for.

`onSuccess` runs immediately after the post request has finished AND in successful. It is completely separated from other links and it's purpose (if your returning a Promise from it) is to delay the execution of the `onFinish` handler.

From the docs:

> It's also possible to return a promise from the onSuccess() and
> onError() callbacks. This will delay the "finish" event until the
> promise has resolved.

I also believe there's some problem in your code: `Promise.all` should receive an array os `Promises` and I'm pretty sure `window.Toast.success(page.props.toast)` isn't returning one, is it?

So... chances are that your `Promise.all` is never resolving.

Comment: Hm, for example: I delete some Data from Database - while this is processing, I click on a NavLink (which redirects me to another Page). So onSuccess is not Loaded meanwhile. How isit possible to finish loading the whole process then?

Comment: So... you stay on the same page while you can have multiple entries being deleted simultaneously. Right? If this is the case, I would try making a $inertia.post just like you did but with preserveState: true and preserveScroll: true, but on the Server side, I'll would redirect to the page you're at. If this doesn't work, you can do it directly with axios.

Comment: Yes if I stay on the same page, but eg. I delete a large amount of data (it takes 10secs) - meanwhile, I dont want to wait, so I will click another Link to make something else - Caus I dont want to wait 10sec :)

Comment: In this case, there's some other considerations: The code that makes the requests must be independent from your page. Because when you click a nav link to go to another page, the page you're currently at will be destroyed. So you need to have some sort of global state. And for it, you can use axios directly.

Comment: yes, I think so, but I thought may in Inertia this is also possible